# Editing a variable in one class doesn't seem to change it in another

Tags: java, variables

Its obviously a really simple issue. However, I can't fix it. I'm making a simple code game in which you have five buttons across the middle that correspond with the numbers 1 through 5. The goal is to answer a question given at the top with numbers. If you pass the given max number for how many times you can guess at a question, I want to change the number of lives you have on the screen. I have 3 classes.

my main method containing class :

public class LevelChanger {

```
protected static int buttoncount = 0;
protected static int buttonlimit = 20;
protected static int answer = 12;
protected static int level = 1;
protected static int lives = 10;
protected static String Hint = "";
protected static String Question = "default text";

public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                CodeGui frame = new CodeGui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
        checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer();

}

protected static void checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer() {

    if (buttoncount > buttonlimit) {
        lives--;
        buttoncount = 0;

    }
}
}
```

action listener class

```
public class ActionListeners implements ActionListener {


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent B) {

    CodeGui Gui = new CodeGui();

    if (Gui.num1.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
        LevelChanger.buttoncount++;
    }
    if (Gui.num2.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
        LevelChanger.buttoncount += 2;
    }
    if (Gui.num3.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
        LevelChanger.buttoncount += 3;
    }
    if (Gui.num4.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
        LevelChanger.buttoncount += 4;
    }
    if (Gui.num5.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
        LevelChanger.buttoncount += 5;
        System.out.println(LevelChanger.buttoncount);
    }

}
}
```

finally the gui class :

```
public class CodeGui extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ActionListeners Al = new ActionListeners();


protected JPanel contentPane;

JTextArea questionArea, hintArea;
JLabel livesleft, lblLevel, Maxbutclick;
final JButton num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

public CodeGui() {

    setTitle("The Code Game");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 602, 411);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    livesleft = new JLabel("Lives Left : " + LevelChanger.lives);
    livesleft.setFont(new Font("Stencil Std", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 14));
    livesleft.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    livesleft.setBounds(10, 347, 126, 14);
    contentPane.add(livesleft);

    lblLevel = new JLabel("level : " +  LevelChanger.level);
    lblLevel.setFont(new Font("Stencil Std", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 14));
    lblLevel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblLevel.setBounds(468, 347, 108, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblLevel);

    ActionListeners buttonL = new ActionListeners();

    num1 = new JButton("1");
    num1.setBounds(10, 229, 89, 23);
    num1.setName("button1");
    num1.addActionListener(buttonL);
    contentPane.add(num1);

    num2 = new JButton("2");
    num2.setBounds(128, 229, 89, 23);
    num2.setName("button2");
    num2.addActionListener(buttonL);
    contentPane.add(num2);

    num3 = new JButton("3");
    num3.setBounds(248, 229, 89, 23);
    num3.setName("button3");
    num3.addActionListener(buttonL);
    contentPane.add(num3);

    num4 = new JButton("4");
    num4.setBounds(374, 229, 89, 23);
    num4.setName("button4");
    num4.addActionListener(buttonL);
    contentPane.add(num4);

    num5 = new JButton("5");
    num5.setBounds(487, 229, 89, 23);
    num5.setName("button5");
    num5.addActionListener(buttonL);
    contentPane.add(num5);

    questionArea = new JTextArea();
    questionArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    questionArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    questionArea.setLineWrap(true);
    questionArea.setFont(new Font("Myriad Web Pro Condensed", Font.PLAIN,
            14));
    questionArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    questionArea.setText( LevelChanger.Question);
    questionArea.setRows(10);
    questionArea.setColumns(5);
    questionArea.setBounds(68, 21, 461, 159);
    contentPane.add(questionArea);

    hintArea = new JTextArea();
    hintArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    hintArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    hintArea.setText("Hint : " + LevelChanger.Hint);
    hintArea.setBounds(95, 278, 397, 58);
    contentPane.add(hintArea);

    Maxbutclick = new JLabel("Max Button count for level : "+  LevelChanger.buttonlimit);
    Maxbutclick.setFont(new Font("Stencil Std", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
    Maxbutclick.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Maxbutclick.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    Maxbutclick.setBounds(321, 263, 255, 14);
    contentPane.add(Maxbutclick);

}

}
```

I am trying to do a check to see if the `buttoncount` is over the `buttonlimit`. Then, decrement `lives`. Which, int turn, should appear in the frame. which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer` is called just once right when you start your app. So you call it, the check in it fails (i.e. is false), and then you don't call it any more. You should call it each time you increment `buttoncount`.

Here is a fixed version of your code. 
Compare it with your version to see what I changed.

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class ActionListeners implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent B) {

            CodeGui Gui = new CodeGui();

            if (Gui.num1.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
                // LevelChanger.buttoncount++;
                LevelChanger.incButtonCount(1);
            }
            if (Gui.num2.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
                // LevelChanger.buttoncount += 2;
                LevelChanger.incButtonCount(2);
            }
            if (Gui.num3.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
                // LevelChanger.buttoncount += 3;
                LevelChanger.incButtonCount(3);
            }
            if (Gui.num4.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
                // LevelChanger.buttoncount += 4;
                LevelChanger.incButtonCount(4);
            }
            if (Gui.num5.getName().equals(((Component) B.getSource()).getName())) {
                // LevelChanger.buttoncount += 5;
                LevelChanger.incButtonCount(5);
                // System.out.println(LevelChanger.buttoncount);
            }

        }
    }


    // ===== //


    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

    public class CodeGui extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        ActionListeners Al = new ActionListeners();

        protected JPanel contentPane;

        JTextArea questionArea, hintArea;
        JLabel livesleft, lblLevel, Maxbutclick;
        final JButton num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

        public CodeGui() {

            setTitle("The Code Game");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 602, 411);
            setResizable(false);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);

            livesleft = new JLabel("Lives Left : " + LevelChanger.lives);
            livesleft.setFont(new Font("Stencil Std", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 14));
            livesleft.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            livesleft.setBounds(10, 347, 126, 14);
            contentPane.add(livesleft);

            lblLevel = new JLabel("level : " + LevelChanger.level);
            lblLevel.setFont(new Font("Stencil Std", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 14));
            lblLevel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            lblLevel.setBounds(468, 347, 108, 14);
            contentPane.add(lblLevel);

            ActionListeners buttonL = new ActionListeners();

            num1 = new JButton("1");
            num1.setBounds(10, 229, 89, 23);
            num1.setName("button1");
            num1.addActionListener(buttonL);
            contentPane.add(num1);

            num2 = new JButton("2");
            num2.setBounds(128, 229, 89, 23);
            num2.setName("button2");
            num2.addActionListener(buttonL);
            contentPane.add(num2);

            num3 = new JButton("3");
            num3.setBounds(248, 229, 89, 23);
            num3.setName("button3");
            num3.addActionListener(buttonL);
            contentPane.add(num3);

            num4 = new JButton("4");
            num4.setBounds(374, 229, 89, 23);
            num4.setName("button4");
            num4.addActionListener(buttonL);
            contentPane.add(num4);

            num5 = new JButton("5");
            num5.setBounds(487, 229, 89, 23);
            num5.setName("button5");
            num5.addActionListener(buttonL);
            contentPane.add(num5);

            questionArea = new JTextArea();
            questionArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            questionArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            questionArea.setLineWrap(true);
            questionArea.setFont(new Font("Myriad Web Pro Condensed", Font.PLAIN,
                    14));
            questionArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            questionArea.setText(LevelChanger.Question);
            questionArea.setRows(10);
            questionArea.setColumns(5);
            questionArea.setBounds(68, 21, 461, 159);
            contentPane.add(questionArea);

            hintArea = new JTextArea();
            hintArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            hintArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            hintArea.setText("Hint : " + LevelChanger.Hint);
            hintArea.setBounds(95, 278, 397, 58);
            contentPane.add(hintArea);

            Maxbutclick = new JLabel("Max Button count for level : "
                    + LevelChanger.buttonlimit);
            Maxbutclick
                    .setFont(new Font("Stencil Std", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
            Maxbutclick.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            Maxbutclick.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            Maxbutclick.setBounds(321, 263, 255, 14);
            contentPane.add(Maxbutclick);

        }

        public void update() {
            livesleft.setText("Lives Left : " + LevelChanger.lives);
            livesleft.repaint();
        }

    }


    // ===== //


    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    public class LevelChanger {

        private static int buttoncount = 0;
        private static CodeGui frame = null;

        protected static int buttonlimit = 20;
        protected static int answer = 12;
        protected static int level = 1;
        protected static int lives = 10;
        protected static String Hint = "";
        protected static String Question = "default text";

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        CodeGui frame = new CodeGui();
                        LevelChanger.frame = frame;
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer();

        }

        protected static void checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer() {
            System.out.println("1) buttoncount = " + buttoncount + " // lives = " + lives  + " // buttonlimit = " + buttonlimit);

            if (buttoncount > buttonlimit) {
                lives--;
                buttoncount = 0;
            }

            System.out.println("2) buttoncount = " + buttoncount + " // lives = " + lives  + " // buttonlimit = " + buttonlimit);

            if (frame != null) {
                frame.update();
            }

        }

        protected static void incButtonCount(int val) {
            buttoncount += val;
            checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer();
        }

    }


    // ===== //
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one issue for sure. However, even after I called `checkbuttonlimitAndAnswer` after each time i incremented `buttoncount`, `lives` still won't decrement on the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: @noobEqualsBlake Yes, I have an idea. I've posted a fixed version of your code.

Comment: your awesome. Looks like the `incButtonCount` and the `update` method fixed it.